# Read bytes array

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vbscript, asmx

In web service I have function that return bytes array.  Now, I call it from VbScript and I need to catch result of this function.  How I can catch result of this function in value that is gone be like a value that function return (bytes array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll call a webservice from `VBScript`, you'll probably to use a `XMLHTTP` object; so, you'll get a base64 encoded string to transform into a byte array.

This links can be helpful:

- [VBScript read/write binary, encode/decode Base64](http://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/)
- [Decoding Base64 Strings (in 10 lines of code)](http://operatingquadrant.com/2009/09/11/vbs-decoding-base64-strings-in-10-lines-of-code/)